# Swap size is getting bigger

Tags: swap

I found some kind of bug. I have my swap partition on a USB (4 GB) and it's OK, but after 10 minutes it's extending (6 GB, 8 GB) and after hours of using my PC, it extended up to 70 GB:

[image]

I don't know what's going on but please help.

Edit:more info

[image: here]

edit 2:for the swap-on command basically sometimes i just move the USB and its just reconnecting

Comment: Please post the output of `free -h` and `swapon`.

Comment: It must be a bug in GUI.

Comment: Your swapon command output is really weird. Please give us the output of these commands: sudo fdisk -l, and sudo blkid, and more /etc/fstab.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of terminal. Post text from it.